# Flask SQL Alchemy listens_for decorator

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am trying to create a to-do list application in Flask. I have a lot of experience with Python but am fairly new to the Flask framework.

I have 3 models - User, Task and Project and I would like for there to be a default project called Inbox that every user has even before creating any projects themselves.

User and Project are related via a many to many relationship.

My attempt at this has been to use the following decorator on a function that creates a new project with a name Inbox.

```
@event.listens_for(Project.__table__, 'after_create')
def create_inbox(*args, **kwargs):
    inbox = Project(name='Inbox')
    db.session.add(inbox)
    db.session.commit()
```

Then, when I create a new User, I add the 'Inbox' project to their projects in the `__init__` function.

This is a class just used to set up the many to many relationship between User and Project:

```
class UserProject(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'userprojects'
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
```

Here is the Project model and decorator to listen for table creation:

```
class Project(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='project', lazy='dynamic') # one project has many tasks
    users = db.relationship('User', secondary='userprojects', lazy='dynamic', backref=db.backref('user', lazy='dynamic'))

@event.listens_for(Project.__table__, 'after_create')
def create_inbox(*args, **kwargs):
    inbox = Project(name='Inbox')
    db.session.add(inbox)
    db.session.commit()
```

Here is the User model:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=True )
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='author', lazy='dynamic') # one user has many tasks
    projects = db.relationship('Project', secondary='userprojects', lazy='dynamic', backref=db.backref('project', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        p = Project.query.first()
        if p not in self.projects.all():
            self.projects.append(p)
```

There is also a Task model but I have not included it here as its not relevant to the problem.

The problem that occurs is when I try to use migrate and upgrade. I perform flask db init, migrate and upgrade and get the following output, so it seems as though its all worked well, and the migration file looks fine.

```
flask db init

Creating directory /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/migrations ... done
Creating directory /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/migrations/versions ... done
Generating /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/migrations/script.py.mako ... done
Generating /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/migrations/env.py ... done
Generating /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/migrations/README ... done
Generating /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/migrations/alembic.ini ... done
Please edit configuration/connection/logging settings in '/Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/migrations/alembic.ini' before proceeding.

flask db migrate

INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'projects'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'users'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'tasks'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_tasks_due' on '['due']'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'userprojects'
Generating /Users/Jasmine/projects/flask/tasky/migrations/versions/64311763e16f_creating_the_tables.py ... done

flask db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 64311763e16f, creating the tables
```

However when I go into `flask shell` and type `Project.query.all()` I get an empty list where I would expect to get a list with one item - a project with a name of 'Inbox'.

I'm not sure where the error is, so any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I've misinterpreted but would you not be better off using an [`after_insert`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert) and create a `Project` instance for Inbox and add it to the newly created `User` object when it's inserted?

Comment: Thanks @SuperShoot for your comment. I've not come across `after_insert` before but will see if it works. Why would it be better than using `after_create`?

Comment: Because it is an event that is bound to the creation of new instances while `after_create` is bound to issuing of create table statements. Is each user going to have their own distinct Inbox instance? Or are they all sharing the same Inbox? I.e. if one user changes theirs, all other users see the changes? Or only the user that made the change?

Comment: @SuperShoot Ok I understand. I do indeed want each user to have their own distinct Inbox instance so it does make sense to use `after_insert` instead of `after_create`. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different ways to handle creation of initial data in your database that I often see, I guess you came up with a third.

One option is to create a script (or custom extension to the `flask` command) that adds all the initial values to the database. For example, after you do `flask db upgrade` you could do `flask db initdb` to have that Inbox project added. You could write this `initdb` function in a way that you can run it multiple times, and it only adds the things that are missing, without creating duplicates.

Another option is to edit your migration script to include adding this data. Alembic provides the [execute()](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.execute) and [bulk_insert()](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.bulk_insert) operations that you can use for this purpose. So after you run `flask db migrate`, you can open the migration script in your editor and hand edit it to include the creation of the Inbox entry. Only after you've made these changes you run `flask db upgrade`.

I think your solution is a little bit overkill. You are setting up an event watcher, for something that is going to occur once in the entire life of the application installation. Consider that this event handler is going to be active during the run of your application, even though it is not needed at all during runtime. I recommend that you use one of the two more direct approaches above instead.

Comment: Brilliant, I have it working now. Many thanks @Miguel for your advice.